# How to set automatic brightness in macbook pro?

Tags: brightness, macbook, macbook-pro

I have just installes ubuntu 14.04 in my macbook pro, and I already configure all but the keyboard and screen brightness.

In OS X, the brightness is controled automatically, I want to know if this is possible to do the same on ubuntu, if can't, then how can I set that do not start with all the brightness, this has been a great bug in ubuntu since the start, a lot of time has passed and this keeps been a real trouble.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Open up a terminal and type in the commands, this will install "wildguppy":

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fantasyleague0629/wildguppy
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wildguppy
```

Then to get it to run type in terminal:

```
wildguppy
```

Lastly if you want to have it boot on startup:

```
wget http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/bcnzhxv6mrmipdd/wildguppy-gtk.desktop -O ~/.config/autostart/wildguppy-gtk.desktop
```

This will hopefully give you what you want.

Comment: This is useful but...It kind of make the opposite of what a automatic brightness should do.
In Mexico is the 11:18 p.m, so the brightness should be the minimum, so my eyes don't get burn with the laptop.

Comment: Can you not edit the settings in the program?

Comment: I actually don't want to, I was hopping that someone know how to make work the sensor that the MacBook Pro has, but if no body answer, then I'll have to use this.

Answer (score 0):

There's another program called f.lux, it adjusts the temperature of the screen according to the lighting and time.

Try it, you might like it. I use both, WildGuppy and f.lux.

To install f.lux :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kilian/f.lux
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install fluxgui
```